# CircularDependencyError SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I am utilizing SQLAlchemy for my current project. Within this project, I have three classes: A, B, and C. These classes are organized in a hierarchical structure. Specifically, I want class C to inherit from class B while also establishing a one-to-many relationship between them. In this relationship, class C can have multiple instances of class B, whereas each instance of class B is associated with only one instance of class C. An interesting aspect of this relationship is that, given C's inheritance from B, C can have a relationship with itself.

So far I have the following code:

```py
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"
    
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "a",
        "polymorphic_on": "type"
    }
    
    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)
    
    
    
class B(A):
     
    __tablename__ = "b"
    
    
    id = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey("a"), primary_key=True)
    
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "b",
                        "inherit_condition": (a.id == id)}
    # associations:
    c_id = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey("c.id", ondelete="CASCADE", use_alter=True), nullable=True)
    c = relationship("C", back_populates="bs", foreign_keys=[c_id])
    
    
    
    
class C(B):
    __tablename__ = "c"
    id = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey("b"), primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "c",
        "inherit_condition": (id == b.id),
    }
     
    
    # associations
    bs = relationship(
        "B",
        back_populates="c",
        uselist=True,
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        single_parent=True,
        foreign_keys=[b.c_id])
```

With the code above I can do the following without any problems:

```py
    b = B()
    c = C()
    b.c = b
    c.bs = [b]
    
    session.add_all([b,c])
    session.commit()
```

However, when I try to establish a relation between a C and it-self, I get the following error:

> E               sqlalchemy.exc.CircularDependencyError: Circular
> dependency detected. (SaveUpdateState(<C at 0x11163b850>),
> ProcessState(ManyToOneDP(B.c), <C at
> 0x11163b850>, delete=False),
> ProcessState(OneToManyDP(C.bs), <C at
> 0x11163b850>, delete=False))

```py
    c = C()
    c.c = c
    c.bs = [c]
    session.add(c)
    session.commit()
```

Is there a way to get rid of this error without changing the schema organisation?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record I wouldn't do this... but I think it can work, you need to use [`post_update`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.post_update) so that the `C()` is flushed and an id comes back that can be then set with an `UPDATE` statement by sqlalchemy automatically.

Note that in your question you do `b.c = b` but a `b` cannot be a `C` so I don't think that should be a valid assignment.  This should `c.bs.append(b)` link the `b` to the `c` though.

```py
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "a"
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "a",
        "polymorphic_on": "type"
    }
    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)



class B(A):
    __tablename__ = "b"
    id = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey("a.id"), primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "b",
        "inherit_condition": id == A.id,
    }
    c_id = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey("c.id", ondelete="CASCADE", use_alter=True), nullable=True)

    c = relationship("C", back_populates="bs", foreign_keys=[c_id], post_update=True)


class C(B):
    __tablename__ = "c"
    id = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey("b.id"), primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "c",
        "inherit_condition": id == B.id,
    }

    bs = relationship(
        "B",
        back_populates="c",
        post_update=True,
        uselist=True,
        cascade="all, delete-orphan",
        single_parent=True,
        foreign_keys=[B.c_id])


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


with Session(engine) as session:

    b = B()
    c = C()
    # @NOTE: A b is not a c.
    #b.c = b
    b.c = c
    # @NOTE: We don't need to do this because of back populates
    # c.bs.append(b)
    session.add_all([b,c])
    session.commit()


with Session(engine) as session:
    c = C()
    # A C is a c so I guess this could work.
    c.c = c
    # A C is also a b but we already linked so this is redundant.
    #c.bs.append(c)
    session.add(c)
    session.commit()

    assert c.c == c
    assert c in c.bs
```